# Mysql query issue with multiple table table join

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, where-clause

Hi this is my tables

table 1 => products

```
id   product  price active
3    sample   1500   1
4    sample2  2300   2
```

table 2 => product_attibute_value

```
id   product  option_value

1     3         Green
2     3         Red
```

and table 3 => product_attribute_options

```
id   product  option_value
1      2        8
2      2        7
```

and my query is

```
SELECT typ.* 
FROM products typ , attibute_value tyav 
WHERE typ.active='1'  AND ( tyav.option_value = 'Green' ) AND typ.id=tyav.product  
GROUP BY typ.id 
ORDER BY typ.price ASC
```

This working fine. Now I want to add product_attribute_options table also.

Now I added new query like this

```
SELECT typ.* 
FROM products typ , attibute_value tyav, product_attibute_options tyop 
WHERE typ.active='1'  AND ( tyav.option_value = '7' OR tyav.option_value = 'Orange' ) OR 
        ( tyav.option_value = '7' OR tyav.option_value = 'Orange' ) AND 
        typ.id=tyav.product OR typ.id=tyop.product  
GROUP BY typ.id 
ORDER BY typ.price ASC
```

I am showing option value in one page, and if i selected this option like 8 or or orange, it will show the product. this product should come from both attribute_options table and attribute_value table.

Its not coming exactly. What I did mistake in this query? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_attibute_value pav ON p.id = pav.product 
INNER JOIN product_attibute_options pao ON p.id = pao.product 
WHERE p.active = 1 AND ( pav.option_value = '7' OR pao.option_value = '7' )
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.price ASC
```

Comment: Sorry my qyestion was wrong. I need  pav.option_value = '7' OR pao.option_value = '7'

Comment: If my query is SELECT p.* 
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN product_attibute_value pav ON p.id = pav.product 
WHERE p.active = 1 AND ( pav.option_value = 'orange' )
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY p.price ASC, it will show the result proper, when I join option table its not coming

Comment: @Prakash What do you want? Be specific

Comment: if my query is 
SELECT typ.* FROM  products typ INNER JOIN product_attibute_value tyav ON typ.id=tyav.product INNER JOIN product_attibute_options tyop ON typ.id=tyop.product where typ.active='1'  AND tyav.option_value = '7' OR tyav.option_value = '7'  OR tyop.option_value = '7' GROUP BY typ.id order by typ.price asc LIMIT 0, 8 
it  comes perfect

Comment: and if my query is

SELECT typ.* FROM  products typ INNER JOIN product_attibute_value tyav ON typ.id=tyav.product  where typ.active='1'  AND tyav.option_value = '7' OR tyav.option_value = 'orange' OR tyop.option_value = 'orange' GROUP BY typ.id order by typ.price asc LIMIT 0, 8 

it  comes perfect

Comment: but its not coming your query

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use `JOIN` sentences and conditions on each of them.

Try this:

```
   SELECT typ.* 
     FROM products typ 
     JOIN attibute_value tyav ON typ.id=tyav.product
     JOIN product_attibute_options tyop ON typ.id=tyop.product
    WHERE typ.active='1'  
      AND ( tyav.option_value = '7' OR tyav.option_value = 'Orange' ) 
 GROUP BY typ.id 
 ORDER BY typ.price asc
```